# Are reputation and badges a valid measure for anything?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Reputation and badges on Stackoverflow are accumulated based on transparent, well-defined and objectively applied rules and primarily measure activities on the site (badges) and judgements (which are based on peer review only) on the content of contributions (reputation). That being said, I wonder if reputation and badges actually are a valid measure of knowledge, skills and ability. I would be very interested in arguments both for and against this assumption.

Comment: Reputation and badges are a measure of how much time one spends on the site ;)

Comment: @Oded true, to an extent. Especially with badges, a novice programmer would have a very difficult time getting some of them.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: I didn't DV, but this question seems a bit... not useful. Interesting perhaps, but I don't see anything constructive/practical coming out of it.

Comment: It's well established that downvotes require no explanation of any kind whatsoever.

Comment: You might appease some downvoters by rewording as *"How can reputation and badges be improved to be a more valid measure for anything?"* or *"Which badges are a valid measure for anything?"* Reputation itself is not utterly subjective, but it's probably too easy to game to be very objective. Some badges are useful. It might be useful to compare rep behavior between tags; some tags are heavy in newbies asking easy questions that can be farmed and are unlikely to be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Badges mostly tell you how long you've been here and as such, I typically ignore these. There are a few special ones like the Guru badge but mostly I feel like badges are promotional and don't really convey anything.

Reputation is a much more solid unit of measurement. However you can't look at it in a vacuum: Unless you are preventing it on purpose, you will always gain reputation if you do possible-reputation-increasing activities (aka: asking & answering). If you go too often downwards, the system will prevent you anyway by question and/or answerbanning you.

Evidently this means that you should take both the reputation of someone and his active timeline in account. But that's not all!

- You also have to look at how many answers have been posted. "Did he gain 10.000 rep with 200 answers, or did he need 2000?" makes a big difference.
- That's still not all! What about people who ask questions? Do 1000 questions make you as skilled as 1000 answers?
- How is the distribution? Did I have 1 answer with 5000 upvotes and 999 answers with 0 upvotes? Or do I have 1000 answers with a mean of 5 upvotes each?
- Are we talking about a user that suggested 1500 edits for 2 rep each, or did he post 100 high-quality answers?
- Did this user gain easy rep when "how do I write the Hello World app in Java"-questions were still acceptable?
- Exactly how many of this person's answers have been on questions closed as a duplicates? Or typographical errors?
- Where were his areas of activity? Are we talking about 20.000 rep in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or 20.000 rep in [mystical-esotherical-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mystical-esotherical-language)?
- What exactly are the contents of his answers.. Did he answer "How do I return a string in Java" or did he uncover secrets of universe as a part of his process to sift through the language specification?
- Or are we talking about an altruistic user who gave away 50.000 reputation in bounties?

---

It doesn't say anything, at best you can get an indication of how active they are and you will probably notice that most of them provide quality answers. If you want to judge a person's expertise based on their SO profile, you'll need to look at many different metrics.

Comment: I feel that rep gets skewed a lot more than badges. It's easy to get a lot of rep off of softball questions. But it's harder to BS your way to 50 great answer badges.

Comment: @Mysticial: fair enough, badges like that are important as well (when looked at with a certain scrutiny, of course).

Comment: Don't forget to include the traffic of the tags that the user is posting it after all in some tags it is easy to get upvotes and others it is harder.

Comment: @JoeW: it's in there (see mystical-esotherical-language)

Comment: I've edited to (IMO) emphasize the points you're making; please feel free to roll back if you feel it was inappropriate. And kudos for a very nicely done answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer given here but would like to add (and yes as a seperate answer):

Reputation and badges is certainly a measurement of something.

If this is a valid measurement of 'knowledge, skills and ability' depends on how you would define that 'knowledge, skill or ability'.

e.g. reputation is certainly a valid measurement of the 'ability to achieve reputation scores' ... and if this is because of 'spending way to much time on this site' or because of 'excellent programming (or other) skills' or because of other... is the discussion as answered above.

The value of this reputation and badges, lies in the value that a community (or in fact anyone) would like to give it...

And this can be as a real-life recognition of certain skills (and in that case these badges and reputation score can be like the Open Badges Standard from Mozilla (openbadges.org))

Or this can just be within this closed community of stackoverflow in which it is more of a game of who can get the highest scores...

Up to others to decide what value they would like to give it..